# Small change to slider navigation

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I'm using this jQuery slider and it works as supposed. But I would like to change the navigation or paging to display "Currently displaying slide y of y" and then the "next" link.

How do I do that? I can see that there's a

```
function current(t) {...}
```

but I don't know how to use it. I guess displaying the "current" and "last" slide is the solution, but how should they be used?

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TrZbn/).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This slider at http://bxslider.com/ has all the functionality I'm looking for.